# How do I Draw a Path Travelled Line in OpenCV, Python for an Object Being Tracked

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tracking

So I have code that can track multiple objects(attached below) how would i make it draw a path that those objects travelled. Answer can be tailored for instances in which I'm only tracking one object. Thanks in advance.(disregard any tabbing errors, I ad to tab them over because stack overflow had issues getting the whole text to be code)

```
'from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import cv2
from random import randint

trackerTypes = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL', 'KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']


def createTrackerByName(trackerType):
# Create a tracker based on tracker name
    if trackerType == trackerTypes[0]:
        tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[1]:
        tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[2]:
        tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[3]:
        tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[4]:
        tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[5]:
        tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[6]:
        tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
    elif trackerType == trackerTypes[7]:
        tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
    else:
        tracker = None
        print('Incorrect tracker name')
        print('Available trackers are:')
        for t in trackerTypes:
            print(t)

    return tracker

videopath = 'vide.mp4'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videopath)

success, frame = cap.read()

bboxes = []
colors = []

while True:

    bbox = cv2.selectROI('MultTracker', frame)
    bboxes.append(bbox)
    colors.append(bbox)
    print('press q to quit')
    print('press any other letter to select next object')
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
        if (k == 113):
            break

if not success:
    print('failed to read video')
    sys.exot(1)

print('bound boxes {}'.format(bboxes))


   trackerType = 'CSRT'

   multiTracker = cv2.MultiTracker_create()

for bbox in bboxes:

    multiTracker.add(createTrackerByName(trackerType), frame, bbox)


while cap.isOpened():
    success, frame = cap.read()
    if not success:
        break
    success, boxes = multiTracker.update(frame)
    for i, newbox in enumerate(boxes):
        p1 = (int(newbox[0]), int(newbox[1]))
        p2 = (int(newbox[0] + newbox[2]), int(newbox[1] + newbox[3]))
        cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, colors[i],2,1)

    cv2.imshow('multitracker', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
       break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: for each point in the track: draw a line to the next point (if available)

Answer (score 1):

You can create and array and push into objects centers by index.
I don't like a MultiTracker API in OpenCV. It's too primitive.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain a little bit more how you would do it. also what would be better than MultiTracker in your opinon